# using db column as img src in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

this is my first time posting here, long time reader though. I can't seem to find an answer to this question so I thought I would ask.

What I am having trouble with is I am trying to display a list of items from a table on a view.

I want to use one of the columns to save URL's for image sources.

So far I have it to where It will display all items saved in the table, But I am having trouble pulling out the string from the imgUrl column. It will display it when I use the span tag but I am not sure how to produce similar results in the image source.

Can I get some help please?

```
<div th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(items)}">
<dl th:each="item : ${items}">
<dt class="itemInfo"> 

<label>Image URL:</label>

                <!-- here is where I try to add the image -->
<img th:src="@{item.imgUrl}"
    src="${item.imgUrl}" width="350" height="200"/>

<span th:if="${item.imgUrl}" th:text="${item.imgUrl}"></span> <br/>
<span th:if="${item.imgUrl eq null}">No image available</span> <br/>
```

Here is where I add the table to a list and add it to the view

```
// inventory view
@GetMapping("/inventory")
public String inventory(HttpSession session, Model model) {

List<Item> itemList = item.findAll();     
if (itemList != null) {
    model.addAttribute("items", itemList);
}

boolean hasUserRole = hasUserRole();
boolean hasAdminRole = hasAdminRole();      
if (hasUserRole) {
    session.setAttribute("userrole", hasUserRole);
}
else if (hasAdminRole) {
    session.setAttribute("adminrole", hasAdminRole);
}
return "inventory";
}
```

Comment: Try to resolving the image src from the span to see if you can resolve the image from a browser. You problem could be that the url is not resolvable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with your image url. The `img` tag doesnt have a proper `src` element pointing to a proper image url. 
From the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

> If we deploy a myapp.war file into a Tomcat server, our application will probably be accessible as http://localhost:8080/myapp, and myapp will be the context name.

So if you are using `<img th:src="@{/user/image1234.jpg}">`. 
Your url will be resolved as`<img src="/myapp/user/image1234.jpg">`

You might wanna debug and re-check your final url in the browser debugger.

Answer (score 2):

yes your are correct. I changed the code to this

```
<img 
 th:attr="src=${item.imgUrl},title=${item.imgUrl},alt=${item.imgUrl}" 
            height="538" width="300"/><br/>
```